# double for loops in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of file names in order. Something like

```
files-1-loop-21
files-1-loop-22
files-1-loop-23
files-1-loop-24
files-2-loop-21
files-2-loop-22
files-2-loop-23
.
.
.
and so on
```

As for testing I have written python code as below:

code sample_1:

```
for md in range(1,5):
   for pico in range(21,25):
      print md, pico
```

It gives me pair of number such as:

```
  `1 21
   1 22
   1 23
   1 24
   2 21
   2 22
   2 23
   2 24
   3 21
   3 22
   3 23
   3 24
   4 21
   4 22
   4 23
   4 24
```

`

if I use:

code sample_2:

```
 for md in range(1,5):
   for pico in range(21,25):
  print "file-md-loop-pico"
```

I get

```
  files-md-loop-pico
  files-md-loop-pico
  files-md-loop-pico
  files-md-loop-pico
  files-md-loop-pico
  files-md-loop-pico
  files-md-loop-pico
```

How (code sample_2) should be altered to get the file lists as I wanted (as shown in the beginning of this post) in python?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
for md in range(1,5):
   for pico in range(21,25):
      print "file-{0}-loop-{1}".format(md, pico)
```

Or:

```
from itertools import product
for md, pico in product(range(1,5), range(21,25)):
    print "file-{0}-loop-{1}".format(md, pico)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string formatting.

```
print 'file-{0}-loop-{1}'.format(md, pico)
```

Comment: Lets say I have three loops, can I use as (  print "files-{0}-loop-{1}-varies-{2}".format(md,pico,jay)  )? Is that possible explain what the meaning {0} and {1}?

Comment: @Vijay sure you can, the numbers are references to which paramater of `format` you want to include in the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

1) Python scope is determined by [indentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html). Your inner code must be properly indented:

```
for md in range(1,5):
    for pico in range(21,25):
        print "file-md-loop-pico"
```

2) You are using a string literal `"file-md-loop-pico"` rather than inserting your variables `md` and `pico`. To [format your string correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format), use:

```
for md in range(1,5):
    for pico in range(21,25):
        print "file-{0}-loop-{1}".format(md, pico)
```

Comment: Considering the output, it's unlikely indentation is the problem; most likely the OP just formatted the SO post incorrectly and not the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

one-liner:

```
print '\n'.join([('files-%d-loop_%d' %(i, j)) for i in xrange(1,5) for j in xrange(21,25)])
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution, provided in the other answers,with arguments surrounded by {} is the correct modern way to do this

```
print'file-{0}-loop-{1}'.format{md,poco)
```

There is an older way to do this that you will probably see, and that might make more sense if you are familiar with c or c++ sprintf

```
print'file-%d-loop-%d'%(md,poco)
```

The documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: You still have to print the result, that just how to format the string

Comment: I've added the print, the parents aren't needed

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem easily:

Code:

```
for md in range(1,5):
       for pico in range(21,25):

            print "file-%d-loop-%d"%(md,pico)
```

Output:

```
file-1-loop-21
file-1-loop-22
file-1-loop-23
file-1-loop-24
file-2-loop-21
file-2-loop-22
file-2-loop-23
file-2-loop-24
file-3-loop-21
file-3-loop-22
file-3-loop-23
file-3-loop-24
file-4-loop-21
file-4-loop-22
file-4-loop-23
file-4-loop-24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for md in range(1,5,1):
  for pico in range(21,25,1):
     print ("file-" + str(md) +"-loop-" + str(pico) )
```